# What does the SMART self test actually test?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

What does the SMART self test actually test?

I can't seem to find a list of the things the test is actually running.

Comment: I use speedfan in windows to read my SMART stats on a per-metric basis. They have a webpage that explains each metric, so you can evaluate what is or isn't important. some metrics just indicate age or other factors only of statistical interest, whereas others (reallocated sector count, for instance) reflect the current state of the drive and its immediate prognosis.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) has a pretty extensive list of the possible error codes, with description.  By seeing what the errors are, you will get a good idea of what is being tested.